# Strapi upload API restrict file types

Tags: strapi, headless-cms

I am using strapi version v4.10.5. We are using strapi upload api (https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/plugins/upload) to upload files to media library. Is there any way to restrict the file types uploaded via this api.